# Why a new node added by appendChild diasppears after leaving the function?

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, appendchild, createelement

Please look at the following code:

```
**page.html**:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Playing with JavaScript </title>
        <script src="myjs.js"> </script>
    </head>

<body id="body">

<ul id="mylist">
    <li> David </li>
    <li> Aharon </li>
</ul>

<form>
<input type="text" name="user_input"> <br>
<button onclick="add_item(user_input.value)"> add_item </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>


**myjs.js**    
function add_item(user_input) {
        var new_li = document.createElement("li");
        var new_text = document.createTextNode(user_input);
        new_li.appendChild(new_text);
        document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(new_li);
    }
```

This code creates a list of two names and displays a button and an input line. Once the user enters a new name in the input line and clicks the button, the new name is supposed to be added to the list.

It happens for a very short period of time and then the new element in the list disappears. Do you know what can I change in the code so the new element in the list will stay permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because your form is submited and page is reload

add a `type="button"` at your button

**Working Example**

```js
function add_item(user_input) {
  var new_li = document.createElement("li");
  var new_text = document.createTextNode(user_input);
  new_li.appendChild(new_text);
  document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(new_li);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="user_input"> <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="add_item(user_input.value)"> add_item </button>
</form>
<ul id="mylist"></ul>
```

`<button>` element have 3 **type** :

- **submit** : **default** type if no type are specified who submit a form
- **reset** : who reset/clear input in a form
- **button** : no specific action

Comment: That solved the problem. But, what is the meaning of writing type="button" inside 'button' tag? Do I actually have to tell the browser that a button is a button ?!

Comment: @CrazySynthax Because default type of button in a `<form>` are submit button. So when you don't specify the type it send the form.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine the page is reloading because your button element is a submit button inside a form - when no `type` attribute is specified for a button it becomes a submit button by default. Your form doesn't have an action specified so submitting reloads the current page.

Add `type="button"` to the button.

That will mean that the button has no default behaviour and does only what the JS does explicitly.

Comment: That solved the problem. But, what is the meaning of writing type="button" inside 'button' tag? Do I actually have to tell the browser that a button is a button ?!

Comment: As I said, by default a button element in a form is a *submit* button, so yes, you have to explicitly tell the browser when you don't want that. I've added an extra note about that to the end of my answer.